# left join query taking forever to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I am having issues with the following query... it takes forever to load... sometimes 10s and others up to 70s which just seems insane to me.

What I am doing is grabbing counts for various activities/tables.  I have read that I should not be putting the conditions in the ON clause because these are outer joins, however, if I don't and put them in the WHERE then I end up with no results... this makes sense as WHERE is for the entire as a whole and I need results from each join.

With that said, why in the world is this query taking soo long?  The plan appears to be working correctly.  The entire db is only 700KiB, but this query always writes to disk and sometimes that tmp file is over 10gig in size... how is that possible?  According to the plan I am getting just what I need which is hardly any rows/information at all.

Using innodb for the db.

Any help would be really appreciated as currently this problem makes no sense at all to me.

```
SELECT
  users.user_id as DT_RowId,
  users.username as username,
  computers.computer_name as computer_name,
  count(distinct log1.activity_id) as log1s,
  count(distinct log2.activity_id) as log2s,
  count(distinct log3.activity_id) as log3s,
  count(distinct log4.activity_id) as log4s,
  count(distinct log5.activity_id) as log5s,
  count(distinct log6.activity_id) as log6s,
  count(distinct log7.activity_id) as log7s,
  count(distinct log8.activity_id) as log8s,
  count(distinct log9.activity_id) as log9s,
  count(distinct log10.activity_id) as log10s,
  count(distinct log11.activity_id) as log11s

FROM computers

INNER JOIN users
    on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id

LEFT JOIN log1
    on log1.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log2
    on log2.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log3
    on log3.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log4
    on log4.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log5
    on log5.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log6
    on log6.user_id = users.user_id AND log6.event_title = 'test1'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log7
    on log7.user_id = users.user_id AND log7.event_title = 'test2'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log8
    on log8.user_id = users.user_id AND log8.event_title = 'test3'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log9
    on log9.user_id = users.user_id AND log9.event_title = 'test4'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log10
    on log10.user_id = users.user_id AND log10.event_title = 'test5'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log11
    on log11.user_id = users.user_id AND log11.event_title = 'test6'

WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status

GROUP BY users.user_id
```

**plan:**

```
computers   1   SIMPLE  ref PRIMARY,unique_filter,status    unique_filter   4   const   5   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
users   1   SIMPLE  ref unique_filter   unique_filter   4   stephen_inno.computers.computer_id  1   Using index
log1    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log2    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log3    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log4    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log5    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log6    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log7    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log8    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log9    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log10   1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log11   1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
```

**EDIT :**

Using Gordon's solution below.  I must say that it is running super fast now, however, I do see something in the plan which is raising an eyebrow.  Here is the plan for one of the left joined tables :

```
<derived2>  1   PRIMARY ALL                 7   
log5    2   DERIVED index       user_id 775     1304    Using index
```

The derived has a type of 'all' and reads 7 rows.  The subquery has a type of index and reads 1304 rows.  1304 is the total number of rows in this database... regardless if it belongs in this query or not - `WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status`.  So it appears this is not going to work unless I am reading it wrong... I certainly do not want to read the entire db for each of these.

Ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

In regards to the problem of scanning the entire table for these joins I thought I could use a subquery in my from and then join onto that.  My thought process here is the result of this subquery will contain only the users I want in my results... so the joins would therefore only join on this set of users.  Unfortunately after looking at the plan the optimizer is still reading every row in the table on the joins rather than joining on the active_users set only.

Ideas?

```
  FROM
    (SELECT
        user_id,
        computer_name,
        username
      FROM computers

        INNER JOIN users
            on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id

      WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status
    ) AS active_users

    ... the left join subqueries (Gordon's answer) follow joining on active_users.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining along multiple dimensions, which is creating a cartesian product for each `user_id`.  A better way to write this query is:

```
SELECT u.user_id as DT_RowId, u.username as username, c.computer_name as computer_name,
       l1.cnt as log1s,
       l2.cnt as log2s,
       . . .
FROM computers c INNER JOIN
     users u
     on u.computer_id = c.computer_id LEFT JOIN
     (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
      from log1
      group by user_id
     ) l1
     on l1.user_id = u.user_id LEFT JOIN
     (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
      from log2
      group by user_id
     ) l2
     on l2.user_id = u.user_id
     . . .
```

Just continue using `left join` to bring in the aggregations for the rest of the log files.

Comment: So use subqueries for each join because I actually want results from each join set?  Is this required because the optimizer can't figure out what I am trying to do or my thought process was actually wrong?

Comment: Joining the same table multiple times as described in your question is usually indicative of poor database design. Considering revising the design

Comment: Yes, using this answer each table would only be joined once, however, I am seeing a new problem (I think) which I have mentioned above in the edit.

Comment: These sub-queries do not have any filtering criteria (check inside the parentheses, there's no `WHERE`), so yes, each one will be scanning the entire table. It saves time because it's simply returning an index value and an aggregate (`COUNT(*)`)

Comment: That is not going to work... if I have 100k rows in a db and only 500 are for this users account then it makes no sense to read all of those.  I was under the impression my condition on `computers` would hold true since I am joining these to it.  The condition on `computers` is what tells the correct records.  As it stands I am reading every row of every table then filtering for the computers condition at the end to get correct results.

Comment: Perhaps a schema redesign is in order, then

Comment: @user756659 . . . Your condition on computers does hold true.  But if there are 10 log records in each of the tables, the resulting processing has 10^11 records, just for one user -- a lot to process.  The database design is probably fine (you have multiple different tables according to the original query).  The query just needs to be improved.

Comment: The design should be fine... it goes from accounts, computers, users, then everything else in that order each linked to the previous by key as a hierarchy.  Been trying to get this correct yet optimized all day.  Any suggestions?